# selenium webdriver code to reply a mail in gmail

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I tried writing code for replying a mail in gmail but was trapped in between

I want to perform below task

1. open the first mail >> able to open the mail
2. reply to mail >> just need a quick idea how I can find the reply image button

please someone suggest..

Comment: Provide the selenium code you have worked on.

Comment: I have used this code:
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox')]")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[@class='yX xY ']")).click();
     driver.switchTo().activeElement();
     WebElement replyButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src, 'images/cleardot.gif')]"));

Comment: tried this and it worked ..

WebElement replyButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.hB.T-I-J3"));

Answer (score 0):

You can find the reply button using:

```
WebElement replyButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Reply']//img"));
```

Comment: Thanks Hinton .. 

I tried the below after opening my first mail from gmail Inbox but still seems script not able to find out the Reply img




driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox')]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[@class='yX xY ']")).click();
WebElement replyButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Reply']//img"));

replyButton.click();

Comment: WebElement replyButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.hB.T-I-J3"));
this works ..

Comment: That may work right now, but that string that you're keying off of is likely to change if you were to logout, clear your cache, and log back in (Or run the test on a different computer/browser). Just something to keep in mind.